# IP configuration for multiserver

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, ip, virtualbox-networking

I have currently a server with IP 127.0.0.1 and Client with IP 127.0.0.2. I want to create a middleman-server in between them which should also work as a server.

How should i assign IP to this new middleman-server.

How to set this ip i am using ubuntu in VMWARE. kindly suggest

Modification :

I designed it with here (gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
name Ethernet alias LAN card
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
network 192.168.1.0

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
name Ethernet alias LAN card
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
network 192.168.1.0

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
name Ethernet alias LAN card
address 192.168.1.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
network 192.168.1.0
```

But i still get following with ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:d5:f0:54  
          inet addr:192.168.28.128  Bcast:192.168.28.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fed5:f054/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:63732 (63.7 KB)  TX bytes:18881 (18.8 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:25691 (25.6 KB)  TX bytes:25691 (25.6 KB)
```

why the new ips are not shown with ifconfig??

Comment: here: name Ethernet alias LAN card   - I think you have to give different names for each of aliases, otherwise you may have collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what exactly you're trying to do - but using loopback interfaces for it is most likely wrong idea.

if you have virtual systems on your vmware host - may be better to create some network like, say, 192.168.1.0/24 and in this network assign separate IP to each of your guests:

i.e.:

192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3

etc.

You can bring interface up with the proper IP using ifconfig command:

ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

However - if you're looking to assign those IPs permanently - you should add them to /etc/network/interfaces.

For example like here:

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

(you can add a proper gateway entry, as well, if needed)

Of course it doesn't have to be 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: How to define gateway??  Would this example solve my purpose ----

    auto lo
     iface lo inet loopback

     auto eth0 
     auto eth0:1
     iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.1
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     iface eth0:1 inet static
     address 192.168.1.2
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     
Also what to do with broadcast , network, gateway???

Comment: I have updated the problem !